# Getting Error 404 Unable to resolve the request "ActionName" when using webapp on server

Tags: php, .htaccess, yii

I create a webapp in yii framework. it is working perfectly on local host but when i deployed it on the server it throwing error :

```
 Error 404 
 Unable to resolve the request "ActionName".
```

I checked all the configuration file all the URLs and paths but not able to find any solution. Even i removed the .htaccess file from my root directory but no solution :( 
Can any body help me to resolve it.

My main.php code is :

```
<?php   

return array(

    'basePath' => dirname(__FILE__) . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . '..',
    'preload' => array('log'),
    // autoloading model and component classes

    'import' => array(

        'application.models.*',

        'application.components.*',

        'ext.giix.components.*', // giix components

    ),

    'modules' => array(

        // uncomment the following to enable the Gii tool

        'gii' => array(

            'class' => 'system.gii.GiiModule',

            'password' => 'jar',

            'generatorPaths' => array(

                'ext.giix.core', // giix generators

            ),

        ),

    ),

    // application components

    'components' => array(

        'user' => array(

            // enable cookie-based authentication

            'allowAutoLogin' => true,

        ),

         'ePdf' => array(

            'class'         => 'ext.yii-pdf.EYiiPdf',

            'params'        => array(               

                'HTML2PDF' => array(

                    'librarySourcePath' => 'application.vendors.html2pdf.*',

                    'classFile'         => 'html2pdf.class.php', // For adding to Yii::$classMap



                )

            ),

        ), 

        'session' => array(

            'timeout' => 300,

            'cookieMode' => 'only',

            'cookieParams' => array('secure' => false, 'httponly' => false),

        ),



        'db' => array(

            'connectionString' => 'mysql:host=localhost;dbname=nameofdb',

            'emulatePrepare' => true,

            'username' => 'UN',

            'password' => 'pass',

            'charset' => 'utf8',

        ),
         'errorHandler' => array(

            // use 'site/error' action to display errors

            'errorAction' => 'site/error',

        ),

        'log' => array(

            'class' => 'CLogRouter',

            'routes' => array(

                array(

                    'class' => 'CFileLogRoute',

                    'levels' => 'error, warning',

                ),


            ),

        ),

    ),
   // application-level parameters that can be accessed

    // using Yii::app()->params['paramName']

    'params' => array(

        // this is used in contact page

        'adminEmail' => 'xyz@abc.com',

    ),

);
```

And my controller code is below :
districtController.php

```
    class districtController extends Controller {
        /**

         * Declares class-based actions.

         */

        public function actions() {

            return array(

    // captcha action renders the CAPTCHA image displayed on the contact page

                'captcha' => array(

                    'class' => 'CCaptchaAction',

                    'backColor' => 0xFFFFFF,

                ),

    // page action renders "static" pages stored under 'protected/views/site/pages'
     ); }

    public function actionIndex() {

     $this->render('index');

        }
    public function actionSda() {


            $this->render('sda');

        }
  public function actionIqt() {

            $this->render('iqt');

        }
  public function actionSm() {

            $this->render('sm');

   }
    public function actionCreate() {

            $model = new SchoolDetails;



    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed

    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);



            if (isset($_POST['SchoolDetails'])) {

                $model->attributes = $_POST['SchoolDetails'];

                $model->setAttribute('school_doc', date('y:m:d, h:m:s'));

                if ($model->save())

                    $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->school_id));

            }



            $this->render('create', array(

                'model' => $model,

            ));

        }



        public function actionUpdate($id) {

            $model = $this->loadModel($id);



    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed

    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);



            if (isset($_POST['SchoolDetails'])) {

                $model->attributes = $_POST['SchoolDetails'];

                if ($model->save())

                    $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->school_id));

            }



            $this->render('update', array(

                'model' => $model,

            ));

        }



        public function actionView($id) {

            $this->render('view', array(

                'model' => $this->loadModel($id),

            ));

        }



        public function actionDelete($id) {

            $this->loadModel($id)->delete();



    // if AJAX request (triggered by deletion via admin grid view), we should not redirect the browser

            if (!isset($_GET['ajax']))

                $this->redirect(isset($_POST['returnUrl']) ? $_POST['returnUrl'] : array('admin'));

        }



        public function actionAdmin() {

            $model = new SchoolDetails('search');

            $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values

            if (isset($_GET['SchoolDetails']))

                $model->attributes = $_GET['SchoolDetails'];



            $this->render('admin', array(

                'model' => $model,

            ));

        }



        public function loadModel($id) {

            $model = SchoolDetails::model()->findByAttributes(array('school_id' => $id));

            if ($model === null)

                throw new CHttpException(404, 'The requested page does not exist.');

            return $model;

        }



        /*  School Operations page actions  Ends  */



        public function actionStudent_create() {

            $model = new StudentDetails;



    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed

    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);



            if (isset($_POST['StudentDetails'])) {

                $school = SchoolDetails::model()->findByAttributes(array('school_name' => $_POST['StudentDetails']['student_school_name']));

                $model->attributes = $_POST['StudentDetails'];

                $model->setAttribute('student_doc', date('y:m:d, h:m:s'));

                $model->setAttribute('school_id', $school->school_id);

                if ($model->save())

                    $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->student_id));

            }



            $this->render('student_create', array(

                'model' => $model,

            ));

        }



        public function actionUpdate_student($id) {

            $model = $this->loadModel($id);



    // Uncomment the following line if AJAX validation is needed

    // $this->performAjaxValidation($model);



            if (isset($_POST['StudentDetails'])) {

                $school = SchoolDetails::model()->findByAttributes(array('school_name' => $_POST['StudentDetails']['student_school_name']));

                $model->attributes = $_POST['StudentDetails'];

                $model->setAttribute('student_doc', date('y:m:d, h:m:s'));

                $model->setAttribute('school_id', $school->school_id);

                if ($model->save())

                    $this->redirect(array('view', 'id' => $model->student_id));

            }



            $this->render('update_student', array(

                'model' => $model,

            ));

        }



        public function actionView_student($id) {

            $this->render('view_student', array(

                'model' => $this->loadModel_Student($id),

            ));

        }



        public function loadModel_Student($id) {

            $model = StudentDetails::model()->findByPk($id);

            if ($model === null)

                throw new CHttpException(404, 'The requested page does not exist.');

            return $model;

        }



        protected function performAjaxValidation($model) {

            if (isset($_POST['ajax']) && $_POST['ajax'] === 'lahaulandspiti-school-details-form') {

                echo CActiveForm::validate($model);

                Yii::app()->end();

            }

        }



        /**

         * This is the action to handle external exceptions.

         */

        public function actionError() {

            if ($error = Yii::app()->errorHandler->error) {

                if (Yii::app()->request->isAjaxRequest)

                    echo $error['message'];

                else

                    $this->render('error', $error);

            }

        }



    }
```

When i am hitting 
http://example.com/abc_new/index.php?r=district&districtId=1
or any other inner url. I am getting the same error.

Please help me get out from this problem.

Comment: whatis ActionName? Put the full stack of errors

Comment: http://example.org/xxyy/index.php?r=district&districtId=1.
When i clicks on any link i got the same error "Unable to resolve the request "ActionName" ". I also checked that controller file name and  link url name are in same case.
there are no error stack only getting above error.

Comment: if you real need help update your question with full error and controller code (only relevant code to your problem). Else you are on your own

Comment: Try to check case sensitivity in your main.php file. If you are transferring from windows to unix then it may create issues ..

Comment: Hello  Stefano Mtangoo.. As i am saying my application i working fine on localhost which says there is no error in my code. There must be any configuration setting has left.

Comment: hi Sanjay Mohnani.. I checked everything regarding case sensitivity. I put all the file name as it as i am calling from url.
if there any other way to set case sensitivity using main.php please let me know..

Comment: the link above does not show the error, you did not paste any relevant code, we do not know what link do you click.. its nearly impossible to help here